# Setting an event handler in JavaScript / Ajax and DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have a site that extracts a set of thumbnail images from MySQL and displays them.

The user selects one of these images by clicking on it, and a larger (intermediate) version of the image is displayed, together with the associated description. This image is placed in a placeholder div (`tablediv`), and the description in another. The data for the intermediate size image and the description is read via Ajax using `XMLHttpRequest`. So far, so good.

What I want to do is set a click event handler on the intermediate image which will open up a full-screen size image in a new window, if the user wants to see a large image.

With the code included in this post, the intermediate size image is displayed and the target function of the `onclick` event is executed straight away. I have replaced my original code for opening a new window with an alert, just for debugging purposes. The code for the image setup follows:

```
list = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('work'); 
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)  {
    var workimage = (list[i].getElementsByTagName("wworkimg")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    var wheight   = (list[i].getElementsByTagName("wworkimgh")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    var wwidth    = (list[i].getElementsByTagName("wworkimgw")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    var wshape    = (list[i].getElementsByTagName("wworkimgs")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    wkimage = workimage;
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.id = 'img';
    img.src = workimage;
    img.alt = 'image';
    img.width = wwidth;
    img.height = wheight;
    document.getElementById("tablediv").appendChild(img);
    document.getElementById("img").onclick = newWindow(wkimage,wheight,wwidth,wshape);
}
```

and the function is coded as follows

```
function newWindow(wkimage,wheight,wwidth,wshape) {
    alert("NewWindow");
    return false;
}
```

When I use Firebug and examine the onclick property, it is null, whereas all other variable values appear to be correct. I have read up this problem in the books I have, as well as referencing on-line manuals, and all the examples I have seen do not seem to be relevant to my case.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `.onclick = function () { newWindow(...); };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking quickly at your code, I'd suggest this:

```
document.getElementById("img").onclick = function() {
    newWindow(wkimage,wheight,wwidth,wshape);
}
```

But it seems you'll also need an extra closure, since you're assigning the handlers in a loop. So:

```
document.getElementById("img").onclick = (function(wkimage,wheight,wwidth,wshape){
    return function() {
        newWindow(wkimage,wheight,wwidth,wshape);
    }
}(wkimage,wheight,wwidth,wshape));
```

---

Now, your `document.getElementById("img")` is really strange. You're creating multiple elements with the same id in the loop, I suggest you do `img.id = 'img' + i;`, and change the `getElementById` call to `document.getElementById("img" + i)`.